# This regular expression never finish. What's going on?

Tags: .net, regex

```
output = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(output, "(?s).*/th>(.*?)<tr class=""summaryrow"">", "$1") + "<end>"
```

I already forget what it's supposed to do. How can regular expression never finish?

What does it try to accomplish? Perhaps I can replace that with strReplace

Comment: Any time you can match most of the pattern several different ways and fail at the end, you get a potential for combinatorial explosion, usually called "catastrophic backtracking". I guess the input has many `<th>` and `<tr`, which allows `.*` and `.*?` to match different number of elements, only to figure out in the end of each try that the class doesn't match. It will terminate... eventually. Your best course of action is using a HTML/XML parser, [not regexp](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/240443).

Comment: what does (?s) match?

Comment: this code use to run fast. not sure what happened. the input is some html document. I am trying to extract the table.

Comment: This could be a stupid question. I write that regular expression. I forget what ?s should match. What does (?s) should match?

Comment: `(?s)` enables [single-line mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx#Singleline). It does not match anything, it is transparent.